# How to show only matching lines?

Tags: search

**Is there a way to hide all lines that did not match, while going through the list of result lines?**

In a long file, I would like to search for a pattern that will match roughly 200 lines or so. The matched lines are in random places in the file.
When a line matches, only the line itself is relevant, no context above or below.

Normally, I would search with `/` and jump through the matches with `n`.
But that means there are only one or two relevant lines on the screen at a time.

A brute force approach would be to delete all non-matching lines, and undo that deletion later. But that's ugly in various ways, even if it would not end up in persistent undo.

Answer (score 69):

```
:vimgrep pattern %
:cwindow
```

[`vimgrep`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#grep) will search for your pattern in the current file (`%`), or whatever files you specify.

[`cwindow`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acwin) will then open a buffer in your window that will only show the desired lines. You can use pretty much any navigating/search command within the `cwin` buffer. Press return to jump to the line under your cursor in the source file.

For help:
`:help vimgrep`
`:help cwindow`

Comment: `:vimgrep` can be abbreviated to `:vim`

Comment: how do i get back to the buffer again?

Comment: also how do i close the buffer? thanks in advance

Comment: From the quickfix (cwindow) buffer you can hit return on any line to jump to that location in the original buffer. You can can close the cwindow buffer from anywhere with `:ccl[ose]` or however you normally close a buffer (e.g., switch to it and `:bd`). You can reopen the quickfix buffer by running `:cw[indow]` again, and it will use your last vimgrep results.

Comment: `:vim YOUR_SEARCH %` and `:cw`, use `ctrl_w,ctrl_w` to switch between frames

Comment: The `%` trick will not work on a `[No Name]` buffer (`E499: Empty file name for % or #`).

Answer (score 41):

You can list all matching lines with

```
:g/{pattern}
```

(The `:print` command can be omitted; it is the default for `:g`.)

Comment: This is the "original grep" (`g/REgexp/p`) ... Problem is that you can't easily jump to one of the matches, though...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: You're right; for that, I have a plugin, see my other answer.

Comment: That could be useful for many cases. Can the output be redirected to a new buffer? That would allow to still have syntax highlighting on the lines. (Hmm... that raises another question, wait a second...)

Comment: @IngoKarkat what is the meaning the `g`. I assume that it is a global pattern. I usually do VI search with a slash `/pattern` and this would find all occurrences. One can navigate to them by pressing the letter `n`

Comment: @AlexanderCska: No, it's not a modifier for search, but a separate command `:g[lobal]` that takes a pattern as an argument. You'll find all details at `:help :global`.

Comment: @IngoKarkat is it possible to redirect the result of `:g/{pattern}` to a file. Say, something like `:g\{pattern}\w file`

Comment: @AlexanderCska Yes, `:redir > {file}` before and `:redir END` after the command(s).

Comment: @IngoKarkat thank you.

Answer (score 26):

[d]elete all lines not(!) matching patterns:

```
:g!/pattern/d
```

or even simpler (thanks for the comments by 'B Layer'):

```
:v/pattern/d
```

Comment: Yeah, but it's more conventional to use the equivalent `:v` rather than `:g!`. (I don't remember the last time I saw the latter used, TBH!)

Comment: If I wasn't used to `v` being "invert" thanks to the `grep` (shell) command, I'd find `:g!` much easier to remember than `:v`. So as a general recommendation I think `:g!` works better.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the `foldmethod` and `foldexpr` options to fold away irrelevant lines.

After searching, the last search is stored in the `@/` register. So, you can readily fold away everything that doesn't match like this (for one-line matches only):

```
:setlocal foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~@/?0:1 foldmethod=expr
```

More advanced methods, like adding multiple levels of folding for context lines you can show or hide, or matching multiple lines, can be found on the [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding_with_Regular_Expression).

Comment: Seems like there is a `set foldlevel=0` needed? But maybe that's default.

Comment: Yeah the default is zero, but if it doesn't work without, adding it can't hurt. :-)

Comment: But now... how to switch it back again, with no traces?

Comment: in normal mode, you can use 'zi' to toggle folding off and on.

Comment: Most of the time when I do this I first `:tab sp` to get a new throwaway view on the file. Then going back is as simple as `:close` or any other way to kill the tab.

Answer (score 10):

If order doesn't matter then just move the lines.

```
:g/pat/m0
```

For more help see:

```
:h :g
:h :m
```

Comment: And `:g/pat/m$` (move the matched lines to the end) is also OK,

Answer (score 3):

If you want to list all matching lines (as in my other answer), and then *jump* to one particular match, my [FindOccurrence plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4922) provides a `[/` mapping for that (and `[n` for the last search pattern, instead of querying for one). `[/pattern` lists like `:g/pattern`, but then asks for the number of the match to jump to.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `:h :ilist`, i use it to get an overview of man page. it's result looks like this:

```
~/find.~
  1:    3 NAME
  2:    6 SYNOPSIS
  3:    9 DESCRIPTION
  4:   18 OPTIONS
  5:   93 EXPRESSION
  6:  779 EXAMPLES
  7:  877 HISTORY
  8:  931 BUGS
```

Here is a small function that let you choose to go to the result line by index:

```
function! s:select_ilist(ilist_result)
  if empty(a:ilist_result) || a:ilist_result =~# '^\_s*Error'
    return
  endif

  let select = input(a:ilist_result . "\ngoto : ")
  if empty(select) | return | endif

  " ilist result starts with '\nfilename\n', filename can be empty
  let lines = split(a:ilist_result[stridx(a:ilist_result, "\n", 1) : ], "\n")
  if select <= 0 || select > len(lines) | return | endif

  exec matchstr(lines[select-1], '^\v\s*\d+\:\s+\zs\d+')
endfunction
```

It can be used like this:

```
command! -buffer Section call s:select_ilist(execute('silent! ilist /\v\C^[A-Z][^a-z]+$/'))
```